# Applescript: Find Difference between two lists of words

Tags: applescript

I have two lists of words. The first one is the Master List. It contains the correct words in the correct order. The second list is missing words and has a few out of order. But the second list crucial because it contains coordinates to the words in the video (number of frames).

FIRST LIST

```
set thePhrase to {"IT", "WAS", "THE", "BEST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "WORST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "AGE", "OF", "WISDOM"}
```

SECOND LIST

```
set theValsPhrase to {{280, "IT"}, {449, "WAS"}, {689, "THE"}, {959, "BEST"}, {1360, "OF"}, {1740, "TIMES"}, {2759, "THE"}, {2879, "WORST"}, {3240, "OF"}, {3379, "TIMES"}, {4420, "WAS"}, {4509, "THE"}, {5239, "WISDOM"}, {5440, "OF"}, {6190, "AGE"}}
```

THE OBJECTIVES: (1) Fill in the missing and out-of-order words. (2) Approximate the value of those missing words.

CONSTANTS: The first words of both lists will aways match.

IMPORTANT: If words are out of order, it would be better to simply treat them as if they were missing. THE MASTER LIST IS THE CORRECT ORDER.

If the script somehow is able to determine where things are missing and how many items in a row are missing, a script like this could put the missing items in an approximate there values:

```
set thePhrase to {"IT", "WAS", "THE", "BEST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "WORST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "AGE", "OF", "WISDOM"}
set theValsPhrase to {{280, "IT"}, {449, "WAS"}, {689, "THE"}, {959, "BEST"}, {1360, "OF"}, {1740, "TIMES"}, {2759, "THE"}, {2879, "WORST"}, {3240, "OF"}, {3379, "TIMES"}, {4420, "WAS"}, {4509, "THE"}, {5239, "WISDOM"}, {5440, "OF"}, {6190, "AGE"}}
-- approximate the value of the first missing value for the first missing word
set x to (((item 1 of item 7 of theValsPhrase) - (item 1 of item 6 of theValsPhrase)) / 3)
set approxVal_01 to x + (item 1 of item 6 of theValsPhrase) as integer
set approxVal_and_Word_sublist to {approxVal_01 as list}
-- add the first missing word from the master list to the temp list
set end of item 1 of approxVal_and_Word_sublist to item 7 of thePhrase
-- approximate the value of the second missing value
set approxVal_02 to (item 1 of item 7 of theValsPhrase) - x as integer
set end of approxVal_and_Word_sublist to {approxVal_02}
-- add the second missing word
set end of item 2 of approxVal_and_Word_sublist to item 8 of thePhrase
-- put it all back together
set tempValsPhrase to items 1 thru 6 of theValsPhrase
set end of tempValsPhrase to approxVal_and_Word_sublist
set theValsPhrase to items 7 thru end of theValsPhrase
set theValsPhrase to tempValsPhrase & theValsPhrase
```

What I really need is a way to find the difference between the text items in both list. I need to fill in the missing words in the second list. I need to replace the out-of-order words in the second list. Finally, I need to approximate resulting missing values in the second list.

Would a different scripting language be more appropriate for this task?

Comment: so where are you stuck in the process ? what error are you getting ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to write a script that finds parts of the two lists that match and fills in the holes for the words and values that are missing or out are of order.

Comment: good question , how dow we know what is the right order ? One could easily figure out how to get the holes filled but how would you know when its out of order and what order to put them into  ?

Comment: Well my example is somewhat flawed because in reality when the two lists are each 155 words long they are about a 90% match. I'm looking for a way to set some kind of threshold. Something like: if 5 words in a row match then set that list to matching_list_01. Once we get all the portions that match, we can fill in all the missing parts.

Comment: You can try my script, it does what you want, it preserve the locations that actually do match and only calculate the missing or out of order ones.
I updated my answer because i made ​​a mistake in my script, I deleted the lines that was after the loop, I put these lines inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set thePhrase to {"IT", "WAS", "THE", "BEST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "WORST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "WISDOM", "OF", "AGE"}
set theValsPhrase to {{280, "IT"}, {449, "WAS"}, {689, "THE"}, {959, "BEST"}, {1360, "OF"}, {1740, "TIMES"}, {2759, "THE"}, {2879, "WORST"}, {3240, "OF"}, {3379, "TIMES"}, {4420, "WAS"}, {4509, "THE"}, {5239, "WISDOM"}, {5440, "OF"}, {6190, "AGE"}}

set finalList to {}
set n1 to 1
set tc2 to count theValsPhrase
set tc to count thePhrase
set i to 1
set found to true
repeat until i > tc
    set tw to item i of thePhrase
    if item 2 of list n1 of theValsPhrase = tw then -- the order is OK
        set end of finalList to list n1 of theValsPhrase
        set n1 to n1 + 1
        set i to i + 1
        if n1 > tc2 then exit repeat
    else -- missing word
        set nextWordL2 to item 2 of list n1 of theValsPhrase
        if found then set lastIndex to i
        set found to false
        repeat with j from (i + 1) to tc
            if nextWordL2 = (item j of thePhrase) then
                set nextFram to item 1 of list n1 of theValsPhrase
                set currFram to item 1 of last list of finalList
                set nF to (nextFram - currFram) div ((j - lastIndex) + 1) -- to approximate : ( the number of frames in this item - number of frames in last item of finalList) divide by (items in a row are missing + 1)
                my addApproxVal(finalList, nF, thePhrase, lastIndex, j - 1, currFram)
                set i to j -- to start at this index in the first loop
                set lastIndex to i
                set found to true
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        if not found then -- no match in the theValsPhrase
            set i to i + 1 --- next item in thePhrase
            set n1 to n1 + 1 --- next  item in theValsPhrase
        end if
    end if
    if n1 > tc2 then -- if the last words in the first list are not in the second list.
        set currFram to item 1 of last list of finalList
        set nF to currFram div (count finalList) -- average 
        my addApproxVal(finalList, nF, thePhrase, lastIndex, tc, currFram)
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
finalList
on addApproxVal(L, nF, L2, k, h, f)
    repeat with m from k to h
        set f to f + nF
        set end of L to {f, item m of L2}
    end repeat
end addApproxVal
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it :) I'll update with comments shortly :)

```
set phrases to {"IT", "WAS", "THE", "BEST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "WORST", "OF", "TIMES", "IT", "WAS", "THE", "AGE", "OF", "WISDOM"}
set locations to {{280, "IT"}, {449, "WAS"}, {689, "THE"}, {959, "BEST"}, {1360, "OF"}, {1740, "TIMES"}, {2759, "THE"}, {2879, "WORST"}, {3240, "OF"}, {3379, "TIMES"}, {4420, "WAS"}, {4509, "THE"}, {5239, "WISDOM"}, {5440, "OF"}, {6190, "AGE"}}

set outlist to {}
set locationCount to 1

-- loop through all the phrases
-- each phrase in phrases are already in the correct order and will simply be coppied to the outlist

repeat with i from 1 to count of phrases
    set currentPharase to item i of phrases

    -- becasue there are missing phrases we have to make sure we account for a shorter location list
    if locationCount is less than (count of locations) then
        set currentLocation to item 1 of item locationCount of locations
        set locationPhrase to item 2 of item locationCount of locations
    else
        set locationPhrase to "" -- list is longer but we still need to test if the phrases match so just setting it to something it will never be equal to
    end if

    -- only do this if we have gone past the first phrase
    if i > 1 then
        set previousLocation to item 1 of (item (length of outlist) of outlist)
    end if
    -- check to see if the phrases match
    if currentPharase = locationPhrase then
        -- some work must be done if we have gone beyond the available locations
        if locationCount is greater than (count of locations) then
            set F to item 1 of item 1 of outlist
            set L to item 1 of item -1 of outlist
            set split to round (previousLocation + getAvergeSteps(outlist, F, L))
            copy {split, currentPharase} to end of outlist
        else
            copy {item 1 of item locationCount of locations, currentPharase} to end of outlist
        end if
    else
        if locationCount is less than (count of locations) then
            set nextLocation to item 1 of item (locationCount + 1) of locations
            set split to round ((nextLocation + previousLocation) / 2)
        else
            set F to item 1 of item 1 of outlist
            set L to item 1 of item -1 of outlist
            set split to round (previousLocation + getAvergeSteps(outlist, F, L))
        end if
        copy {split, currentPharase} to end of outlist
        set locationCount to locationCount + 1 -- there was a location missing so lets up the location count
    end if

    set locationCount to locationCount + 1 -- location count is increased every round
end repeat

on getAvergeSteps(outlist, firstLocation, lastLocation)
    set LocationTotal to count of outlist
    -- get the estimate average change in steps to estimate what the numbers go in when we have gone beyond the number of locations available
    return round (((lastLocation - firstLocation) / LocationTotal) / 2)
end getAvergeSteps
return outlist
```

Comment: That's a pretty good start. Unfortunately the location values are not even close to approximate. I haven't had a chance to really look at the coding but I'm getting the feeling that this may be far more complicated than I originally thought.

Comment: I will be updating the "approximations"  here shortly

Comment: This looks really good. I still haven't had time to pick it apart. I did notice that with a longer document (150 words), even when the first 35 words from the speech analysis file match perfectly with the Master List the values begin to diverge after about seven words. Is there a way to preserve the locations that actually do match and only calculate the missing or out of order ones?

Comment: it does keep the matching words until it finds mismatched word or out of order word then all bets are off. I'm not sure how you would able to tell when things properly matched again

Comment: I'm just curious if there is a scripting language better suited for this. Is there a library in another language like python that is built to find where strings of text match and where they diverge?